# Iterate JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string like this

```
{"3560" : "something", "3980" : "something", "4580" : "1456"}
```

How to get data above as "key -> value" in javascript(jquery) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```

Then you could access the data like `obj.3560` or `obj.3980` or iterate over them using a for-in loop like in Felix Kling's answer.

This requires jquery 1.4.1 or later to work.

Comment: If I use obj.3560, obj.3980 etc. I will get only the "value" of 3560, 3980.
I`m trying to get and the key (3560, 3980) also

Comment: @John - They will be contained in the obj var.  This was just an example on how to access the value after you parse it.  Do a for-in loop and you will be able to access the keys as well.

Comment: `obj.3560` should not work as a number is not a valid identifier.... does this really work for you?

Comment: @John: Is the for loop in my answer not example enough?

Comment: @ Felix Kling: With the example you showed I got only values, but not the keys

Comment: @John: `key` is the key. That is why I named it `key`. E.g. you could do `console.log(key + ": " + obj[key])`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Now you can access `obj["3560"]`, etc.

Or iterating:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    // do something with obj[key]
}
```

Comment: is JSON.parse now included in every browser?

Comment: @Anders: Actually I'm not 100% sure in which browsers it is supported, but it can always be included: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js I would not include jQuery for only parsing JSON. But if it is used anyway, then `$.parseJSON()` should be preferred.